# Оптимизация построения LiveChart

Tags: c#, wpf, livechart

Помогите оптимизировать LIVECHART В C# WPF или как использовать другую библиотеку. Мне нужно строить график где генерируется большое количество точек

```
    private void GraphButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string qdates = "SELECT DATETIME, PRESS FROM A1";
        
        
        List<string> dates = new List<string>();
        ChartValues<double> press = new ChartValues<double>();

        //Получаем результаты времени и давления
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(qdates, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            dates.Add(Convert.ToString(reader.GetDateTime(0)));
            press.Add((double)reader.GetDecimal(1));
            
        }
        reader.Close();
        
        LiveChart(dates, press);

        

    }

    public void LiveChart(List<string> dates, ChartValues<double> press) 
    {
        SeriesCollection series = new SeriesCollection();
        cartChart.AxisX.Clear();
        cartChart.AxisX.Add(new Axis
        {
            Title = "Даты и время",
            Labels = dates
        });

        LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
        line.Title = "Давление";
        line.Values = press;

        series.Add(line);


        cartChart.Series = series;
    }
```

Comment: `генерируется большое количество точек` - какое такое большое? `или как использовать другую библиотеку` - почему вы думаете, что проблема в библиотеке? Я вот вижу, что у вас каша, где нету даже простых привязок. Может стоит тогда для начала выяснить что именно у вас тормозит, а уж затем выяснять как это испрвить?

Comment: Я впервые работаю с WPF и livecharts (cartesian chart) компонентами, поэтому не знаю может ли cartesian chart работать с бесконечно пополняющейся базой. Я бы объяснил все в вопросе изначально, но ограничение не позволило. Проблема в том что новая точка появляется каждые 5 секунд и в следствии график из-за большого количества этих точек начинает знатно так лагать. Вот я и интересуюсь имеет ли смысл использовать эту библиотеку и если да то как ее оптимизировать? А если нет, то есть варианты более подходящие для этой задачи?

Comment: Бесконечное количество точек не влезет на экран.

Comment: Я понимаю что бесконечное количество точек не влезет, можно сделать так например чтобы отображалось 20 точек например и возможность скролить график?

Comment: Я смотрел официальную доку livechart но там я нечего так и не понял, примеров использования не нашел

Comment: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/Wpf/start